# When implementing AppLinks, the Facebook app creates a special button on the status bar and the app doesn't open up directly

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, applinks

I have added the meta tags in the webpage and I am using the method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` to handle the incoming links, but my app doesn't open up directly. The user has to click on that special button on the status bar in the Facebook's browser in order to open the app.

Please help!

Comment: This is the behavior from the Facebook app on iOS.

Comment: Is there some documentation on this behaviour? Ie. documentation about Facebook's implementation of Applinks/bolts etc.

Comment: @Mark Gibaud I didn't find one.

Comment: Me neither - and in fact the official FB documentation is misleading as it doesn't mention anything about another button on the toolbar, but instead has a diagram indicating that a fast-app-switch will happen when they click the content in their newsfeed #failbook

Comment: I agree :P For some apps like Quip it opens up directly after clicking on that "another button" on the toolbar once or twice. Don't know how that works.